# No Captcha in DNN Enquiry Form

Tags: module, dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-5

So I've tried a few times, and a few different versions; but I cannot get the captcha to show up in any browser for the life of me on the Enquiry Module. It's a broken image.

Anyone else running into this issue? This looks to be a very basic module, and I see it being used everywhere online. I don't think I'm messing up, but please correct me if I'm wrong.

I can't get the form to process without the captcha requirement, and this is really putting me behind on moving forward. I would appreciate any tips or advice you may have to offer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just upgraded to DNN v5.6.2, uninstalled the Enquiry, reinstalled it, and now everything works well. Awesomeness! :)